# Authenticate to Calypso smartcard using SAM

Tags: smartcard, sam

I'm trying to write on a SAM-protected Calypso (ISO14443-B) card.
I know its structure, I've managed to write on a Free record, but now I have to use the SAM to write in a private slot.

Using a ACR122L reader with my SAM in the first slot, I have difficulties finding information about the protocol to follow :

I think I'm supposed to select the EF to write on, then issue the GetChallenge command, and use its result to compute a cypher, before being able to write on the file.

Am I right ? The GetChallenge command returns a good-looking response (like 030d1ebe68a5b7189000), but how am I supposed to proceed from there ?

Thanks a lot.